How to convert a question posted by mistake as a Discussion to a Question?
I made a mistake by posting a "question" as "discussion" yesterday.
However, when I tried converting the discussion post into a question post, I couldn't find that function.
Once I post it as a discussion, can't I convert it to a question?
I would like to know how to convert a mistake posted as a discussion into a question.

There isn't a way to "convert" a Discussion to a Question; you need to Ask [a] Question.

Just delete it (I did this part for you) and post a question. You can hit edit on your discussion and copy & paste its content to your question. But make sure you read the [tour] and your question contains a minimal reproducible example.

There is no feature to convert a Question/Discussion to the other. If you make a post in an area of the site it is off-topic then it will most likely be closed and/or deleted.
If, for example, you post a question in the Discussion area of the site, then you would need to repost that question as a Question, using the Ask [a] Question button. If you posted a Question, but it's actually more of a discussion, then you would need to Start [a] Discussion.
Before (re)posting your post, please ensure that it meets the guidelines of the other part of the site. Just because your Discussion was deleted as it wasn't appropriate for that area of the site doesn't mean it's appropriate to be posted as a Question on Stack Overflow. Make sure, as M-- mentions, to read the tour for the site you're asking the question on, and ideally have a read of some of the asking articles in the help centre, such as What topics can I ask about here? and How do I ask a good question?. Don't forget, as well, there are lots of sites within the Stack Exchange Community, so if your question isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow, it might be on a different community.
For Discussions, what's permitted to be discussed is more broad, but there are still guidelines you should read prior to posting.
